# what does `=` in destructure mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Recently, I read a js file, there's a destructure like below,

IMO, I would write `const { files } = obj.props;` , but 
what does `const { file=[] } = obj.props` mean?
why write like this and what's the benefits of this?

```
const obj = {
  props: {
    files: [1, 2, 3],
  },
};

const { files = [] } = obj.props;
// const { files } = obj.props;
console.log(files);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Default values
>
> A variable can be assigned a default, in the case that the value unpacked from the array is undefined.

[Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values)

```js
const obj = {
  props: { not_files: 1 },
};

const { files = ["default", "value"] } = obj.props;
console.log(files);
```

Answer (score 2):

It takes the empty array as default value for the missing property. More under [default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values) or [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

```js
const obj = { props: {} };
const { files = [] } = obj.props;

console.log(files);
```